# How to serialization Raw Html Json data from controller using ajax call?

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I have some code that converts a view-model type into json data so I can bind to some angular js. The code works smoothly as advertised.

Simplified by extension method.

```
public static IHtmlString GetJson(this Object model, WebViewPage page)
{
    return page.Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, 
            new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter()));
}
```

And in my razor view it is easy to use.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var raw = @(Model.GetJson());
</script>
```

However, when I make an ajax call from my client code I get json back differently.

```
public JsonResult GetModel() { 
   return Json(Model);
}
```

Consumed using javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({ url : "/Home/GetModel",
           success: function(json) { 
             // The format is different here and not compatible 
             // with my angularjs
        }});
</script>
```

The json is loaded properly through the GetJson()

[image]

However, the ajax call doesn't work so well.

[image]

Comment: What is `Model` and its properties?

Comment: The model is a view model with various lists. The code for the model is the same for both for the view as it is for the Json result. This(Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter()))) seems to work somewhat, although I am not sure the structure is the same. The result is in a string so I have to call JSON.parse in the client success method.